# Android is not ducking sound (react-native-sound)

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

iOS is ducking sound just fine, but the Android is not ducking. Should ducking be the default behaviour for Android with this module?

Is there a way to duck the audio through react-native-sound or any other method?

Comment: What do you mean by ducking.

Comment: Ducking means that the other sound source lowers it's volume. If the device playing for example a song from spotify, the song's volume should be 'ducked', so that the sound played by react-native-sound is heard more clearly. I am using a module called react-native-tts (https://github.com/ak1394/react-native-tts), which has a ducking option - "
Enable lowering other applications output level while speaking (also referred to as "ducking")."